# How to use private cocoa pod

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have recently created private cocoa pod for my static framework, it is working fine on system on which it is created. But while sharing it with team, it show error **no such a module**

We have following commands on terminal on our project path

```
pod repo add [POD_SPEC_NAME] [POD_SPEC_GIT_URL]
pod repo update
pod install
```

If i create new project every thing working fine, but in my current project. I am getting no such a module.